# is a pod DNS can be reached (with dig or nslookup)?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I understand that pods are isolated into another subnet (POD-CIDR, CNI...)
Is that possible to reach a pod (using a tool)? I saw that you can use ClusterIP, LB, Externalname, but I cannot reach my pod's ipaddress.

Comment: where from do you want to reach a pod by DNS name? please clarify the question as it is unclear at the moment. What is that you would like to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that means something is wrong with your networking. Kubernetes imposes the following fundamental requirements on any networking implementation (barring any intentional network segmentation policies):

1. all containers can communicate with all other containers without NAT
2. all nodes can communicate with all containers (and vice-versa) without NAT
3. the IP that a container sees itself as is the same IP that others see it as

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a service defined for your pod (deployment) you can use kubectl to forward local ports to that service. For example:

`$ kubectl port-forward redis-service 6379:6379 --namespace=default`

This would allow you to access your pod/service through local port 6379

[Kubernetes Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/)

---

If you are interested in making your pod publicly available, your best resource would be to define an ingress. This will allow you to map a public DNS hostname and path to your internal kubernetes service

[Ingress Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)

Comment: you dont really need service for the pod, each pod has its own dns name even without a service